# How to get access outside HTDOCS with PHP script

Tags: php, joomla, htdocs

I have a webserver with Apache.

For security reasons my customer wants to access files (.jpg/.pdf/.png/.gif) in another folder.

The root layout is as follows:

- backup
- data
- etc
- htdocs
- logs
- tmp

In the htdocs folder the Joomla website resides. I use flexicode to add PHP code to the site.

Is there a way I can show for example a photo in .jpg from the data folder?
example. /data/werknemers/80111/pasfoto.jpg

There is a little snag. Everybody uses a pin number to log into Joomla. In this case pin 80111.
Pin 80111 is added to the users table, the field is called pin.

Is it possible to use a variable to retrieve the data? So only user 80111 can access his or her folder and not another one?

The photo is shown in a module on the website after login.

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a php script in joomla (for the authorisation), and give apache access to the external folder. Then deliver your files using this script.

Comment: Hi veelen, thanks for your comment. The login is changed to connect to a LDAP server so I have PIN, username and password. This works. So once users login I only want to show them their photograph.
Do you have an example of a PHP script I can work with?

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: Hi veelen, how can this be done? I mean give access to the external folder?

Comment: You can just call your img as you would normally, but not using a http request, but including it from with php

Comment: Ok but how would the script look like? I understand you can't access it via http request. Since we are logged in we can access the system but I'm not a "hardcore" programmer. I need a little bit of input on this.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/php-link-to-image-file-outside-default-web-directory

Comment: Ok, this is more like it. I'll take a look Veelen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Joomla user, but my first chance will be to look for some plugin to manage the uploads, I saw some plugins to manage uploads per user doing a quick google search, for example [this one](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction/12685).

In the case that no one works for you I think the next option will be try to implement an asset proxy.

- Write an script in htdocs to validate the PIN and if it is ok read the file content from the data directory and provide the output from that script.
- An rewrite rule to redirect all .jpg/.pdf/.png/.gif request for that proxy will be need.
- Be aware to serve the non secure content (theme images for example) as well.

Hope this help

Comment: Hi Casivaaguston,

Thanks, I will take a look at this.

Cheers,

Steve