# Displaying images from outside of web root not working?

Tags: php, html, security

I am trying to display user images stored outside of the web root directory (for security purposes). I have tried the suggestion put forth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/php-link-to-image-file-outside-default-web-directory) however when I navigate to `show_imgs.php`, my browser returns a bunch of gibberish symbols and seems to go into an infinite loop.

The only thing different about my code vs. the example is that my code is in a loop. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

My code:

```
$image_array = ["img_1.png", "img_2.png", "img_3.png"];

$i = 1;
foreach($image_array as $image) {

    //Specify absolute path
    $image_path = "/absolute/path/to/img_$i.png";

    //Get file contents. I have also tried readfile() in place of this.
    $contents = file_get_contents($image_path);

    //Perhaps this is causing the infinite loop?
    header('Content-type: image/png');

    //Display contents of file (aka the image)
    echo $contents;

    $i++;
}
```

And of course I will want to add file size and mime type verification before using `file_get_contents` for security (if there are more security checks I should do please say so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you won't be able to loop and send multiple images.  one php file will output one header and one image.  you'll have to call it again to get another image.

"This way you can call an image like:"

/image.php?file=myfile.jpg

where images.php is the php file that has the header and image read in it.

**images.php:**

```
$file = basename(urldecode($_GET['file']));
$fileDir = '/path/to/files/';

if (file_exists($fileDir . $file)) {
    // Note: You should probably do some more checks 
    // on the filetype, size, etc.
    $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . $file);

    // Note: You should probably implement some kind 
    // of check on filetype
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    echo $contents;
}
```

**my.html:**

```
<img src="images.php?file=myimage.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: So you're saying I should do these operations in images.php and then call the images in display_the_images.php? And would this have to be done in the URL and then using GET or could it be done in the display_the_images.php's PHP script alone?

Comment: so one file (images.php in the example...but you can name it whatever you like) has php in it that will "go fetch and read out" the image outside the doc root.  then in your html where you normally put the image...you put that php file with the GET var on it to let images.php know which image to go and get.