# Going up a path when webpage url is in localhost

Tags: html, css, directory

I have an image whose url is `../path/to/image`, but the `../` doesn't work. The url for my webpage is `http://localhost:8080/account.html`. I can't seem to find a solution online.

I believe the directory is relative to the webpage url. I've tried starting from `file:///C:/` and it works, but I don't want to use that because my other clients will use the domain name, which in this case is localhost.

Is there a way to solve this without moving folders?

Comment: You cannot link to a file that is not publicly accessible. Your server is not serving that file to the user so it cannot be accessed directly.

Comment: @Profit so I should just move it?

Comment: You can either move it somewhere within your web directory or allow the user to access it through a serverside script. Here's a solution using PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/php-link-to-image-file-outside-default-web-directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this `/path/to/image.jpg`

Remove the dots and just add this -> / at the start of the path , that means that the path is going to root directory

Comment: That evaluates to `file:///C:/path/to/image.jpg` for me.

Comment: Then you have do something wrong with the root folder in localhost, what localhost app do you use Wamp ?

Comment: I use Node.js, Express and Socket.io